# What's the difference between 'commerce-line-item-unchanged' and 'commerce-line-item'

Tags: commerce, rules

In drupal commerce rules there are selectors like 'commerce-line-item' and 'commerce-line-item-unchanged' – what is the differnece between them? When should i use the one or the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commerce line items are [Drupal Entities](https://www.drupal.org/node/1261744) (enhanced a bit by the [Entity module](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity)) and, like other entities, the "entityname-unchanged" is present in some rules just so you can see what the entity was like before it got changed.

There isn't a specific use case intended for it but there are cases where being able to see the original state of an entity would be good.  Specific to a commerce line item, maybe you'd want to reset the line item's quantity to its old value if they chose some crazy number like 10000.